# How do I validate an Ember Select list?

Tags: ember.js

I am using the code below to validate if a TextField is empty or 0 and then appending an error class to it to give it a background colour.

I have another textfield that is hidden and has a value set based on what is chosen in an Ember.Select, if a value is not chosen how would it be best to add/change a error class for the select?

```
App.NumField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  required: function() {
    var valid = /^[1-9][0-9]*$/.test(this.get('value'));
    return valid
  }.property('value'),
  classNameBindings: 'required:notreq:req'
});

{{view App.NumField valueBinding="type"}}
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.Type" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.type" valueBinding="type" prompt="Please select a type"}}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in a very similar way by extending an Ember.Select and binding a valid or invalid class based on the outcome if the select selection was null or undefined. I'm not sure if this is the best solution so let me know if you know of a better way. This was quick and works well for me though.

```
App.SelectValidate = Ember.Select.extend({
    validate: function() {
        var chosen = this.selection,
            valid;
        if (chosen === null || chosen === undefined) {
            valid = false;
        } else {
            valid = true;
        }
        return valid
    }.property('value'),
    classNameBindings: 'validate:valid:invalid'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We use Parsley.js  (http://parsleyjs.org/) to validate our forms and in conjunction with that, we just extend our Ember.Select class to include "required" and the "parsley-error-message" attributes so we can use them in our bindings.

```
Ember.Select.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['required', 'data-error-message']
});

{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding="[Your Val]"
optionValuePath="[Your Val]"
optionLabelPath="[Your Val]"
valueBinding="[Your Val]"
prompt="Choose Option"
required="required"
data-error-message="Please select an option."}}
```

So you can see how you can extend the control to handle more parsley validation scenarios by looking at the documentation at parsleyjs.org, it's a nicely done library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working to integrate [parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/) into your CLI project, here is how I set that up.  It has a good number of attributes.

Created `initializers/reopen-textfield.js` as:

```
export default {
  name: 'textfield-configuration',
  initialize: function() {
    Ember.TextField.reopen({
      attributeBindings: [
        'parsley-type',
        'parsley-required-message',
        'parsley-type-email-message',
        'required',
        'placeholder'
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

Created `initializers/reopen-checkbox.js` as:

```
export default {
  name: 'checkbox-configuration',
  initialize: function() {
    Ember.Checkbox.reopen({
      attributeBindings: [
        'parsley-type',
        'parsley-required-message',
        'parsley-type-email-message',
        'parsley-group',
        'required',
        'placeholder'
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

I am using the [ember cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) project to build my ember application.

Current setup at the time of this post:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 vendor.js:15554
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a vendor.js:15554
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 vendor.js:1555
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```